# How to calculate the pixel width of a String in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

It appears that there is no API call to calculate the width (in pixels) of a text string in Java FX 2.2.  There have been suggestions of workarounds on other forums, but my efforts to create or find any code that returns the width of a String, either using the default font or otherwise, have failed.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you are just measuring the default font without CSS:

1. Place the String to be measured in a Text object.
2. Get the width of the Text object's layout bounds.

If you need to apply CSS:

1. Place the String to be measured in a Text object.
2. Create a throwaway Scene and place the Text object in the Scene.
3. Take a snapshot of the Text (if you are using Java 7) or call [applyCss](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#applyCss--) for Java 8.
4. Get the width of the Text object's layout bounds.

This works because it forces a layout pass on the Text which calculates it's layout bounds.
The scene in step 2 is required because that is just the way the CSS processor works (it needs a node to be located in a Scene to be able to do its job).  Definitely read the linked javadoc for applyCss if you want to understand the processing further.

**Sample Code**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

// displays the width in pixels of an arbitrary piece of text.
public class MeasureText extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    final Text text = new Text("XYZZY");
    new Scene(new Group(text));

    // java 7 => 
    //    text.snapshot(null, null);
    // java 8 =>
    text.applyCss(); 

    final double width = text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();

    stage.setScene(new Scene(new Label(Double.toString(width))));
    stage.show();
  }
}
```

Sample program output (displays the width in pixels of an arbitrary piece of text):

[image: Sample Program Output]

> How (if at all) would this change if the text was printed to a graphicscontext with a set font?

Apply the font to a text object containing the same message you will plot to the canvas.  Unlike when you are measuring text plotted to the scene graph, items plotted to a canvas do not have CSS applied to them, so you don't need to place the Text object in a scene and have CSS applied to it before measuring the text.  You can measure the layout bounds of your text object and it will be the same as the bounds of the text plotted within the canvas with the same font.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

// displays the width in pixels of an arbitrary piece of text (which has been plotted on a canvas).
public class MeasureText extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final String msg = "XYZZY";
        final Text text = new Text(msg);
        Font font = Font.font("Arial", 20);
        text.setFont(font);

        final double width = text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(200, 50);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setFont(font);
        gc.fillText(msg, 0, 40);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(
                new VBox(new Label(Double.toString(width)), canvas))
        );
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: is this tool calculate the width of string according to the OS that works on if I want to calculate the text width on Windows and Mac OX ?

Comment: Yes, the correct width will be returned, regardless of OS used.

Comment: Will this solution also account for styled text if the style is applied to the text before the snapshot is taken?

Comment: Why take the snapshot instead of just accessing the layout bounds?

Comment: @Urs A snapshot is used to force a CSS layout pass for Java 7.  I updated my answer to further explain this.

Comment: @jewelsea How (if at all) would this change if the text was printed to a graphicscontext with a set font?

Comment: Updated answer for additional question of measuring text plotted to a GraphicsContext.

Comment: Interested readers can have a look at [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090775) enhancement request.

Answer (score 18):

I tried this:

```
Text theText = new Text(theLabel.getText());
theText.setFont(theLabel.getFont());
double width = theText.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
```

and it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 15):

This solution works up until java 8:

```
float width = com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit().getFontLoader().computeStringWidth("", gc.getFont());
float height = com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit().getFontLoader().getFontMetrics(gc.getFont()).getLineHeight();
```

Those classes have since been removed and are not available in newer java version!

Comment: This can also be used in unit tests and elsewhere, because (as opposed to snapshot) it doesn't require the code to be executed on an FX application thread.

Comment: Sadly this is a discouraged access... It is not on the api as of Java 8.25

Comment: @Supuhstar GraphicsContext

Comment: I really like this solution which is kind of yours: FontMetrics metrics = Toolkit.getToolkit().getFontLoader().getFontMetrics(yourFontObject); and then you can do the fancy FontMetrics stuff with it ([more info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html))

Comment: `com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit` is a restricted, non-public, undocumented class albeit being actually accessible, usage is highly discouraged as it can (and will!) be replaced at some point. **Never** use undocumented classes, these are always **temporary** solutions and will break your code with some update in the future. in general, the entire `com.sun` package should be avoided

Comment: DON'T use this. I used this way of doing it and now I am screwed because the classes are not available any longer. This answer should be removed imho

Answer (score 1):

```
Bounds bounds = TextBuilder.create().text(text).font(font).build().getLayoutBounds();
double width=bounds.getWidth();
double height=bounds.getHeight();
```

Comment: TextBuilder is deprecated.

Comment: Doesn't work for javafx 8, since the `TextBuilder` class was removed.