# How to calculate Label width in JavaFx before adding it to the node?

Tags: label, javafx

Is there is any way to calculate width of Label base on added text, before adding it to Parent node? to Scene?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the pixel width of a String in JavaFX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015698/how-to-calculate-the-pixel-width-of-a-string-in-javafx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fx8 you have to call impl_processCss(true) on the node