# JavaFX synchronize Scroll pane content changes and its Vvalue

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a Scrollpane containing 5 Titledpanes(Categories) each containing 2 images. Height of each TitledPane is 200 in expanded state and 25 in collapsed state.

Here is the image :

[image: Launch screen]

I have a text field in which I can enter the number of the Image to be selected.

For example, If I enter "4", the scroll pane scrolls to the Image-4 in Category-2 as shown below.

[image: Expected]

I am able to achieve this by calculating the Vvalue of the scroll pane based on the height to be scrolled and total height of the content inside the scrollpane.

**Here is the issue**

In the above example, if Category-2 is collapsed, I have to "Expand" it and then move to Image-4.

I am doing this by using the following code algorithm :
   // Let the height of the scroll pane content with TitledPane-2 in collapsed state be (**ht_ScrollPaneBefore** = 825) and ScrollPane view port height be (**ht_Viewport** = 180). Let the ht of the scrollpane after expansion of TitledPane-2 be **ht_ScrollPaneAfter** which is calculated in step 3 in the following algorithm.

```
{       
   ....
   1. Expand TitledPane-2
   2. Call applyCss() and layout() on the TitledPane to make the Expansion effective.(As addressed in the other query : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152642/get-the-height-of-a-node-in-javafx-generate-a-layout-pass)
   3. Get the height of the total Content(ht_TotalContent) of the scroll pane with the expanded TitledPane-2.(ht_ScrollPaneAfter = 1000)
   4. ******  Calculate the Vvalue based on (ht_TotalContent).(let it be Vvalue = 0.56) ***** 
   5. Set the Vvalue to the scrollpane.
   ....
}
```

**Issue**

Since the expansion of the Titledpane is not yet applied "Visually" on the view, the Vvalue(0.52) is getting applied relative to ht_ScrollpaneBefore(800) which is leading to an incorrect scrolling ht as shown in the "Actual output" below.

**Actual Output:**

[image: Actual]

**Expected:**

[image: Expected]

Note: The ht of the scrollpane after the expansion of the TitledPane-2 is obtained successfully using the procedure described in the link: [Get the height of a node in JavaFX (generate a layout pass)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152642/get-the-height-of-a-node-in-javafx-generate-a-layout-pass). The Vvalue has been calculated based on ht_ScrollPaneAfter only **not on** ht_ScrollPaneBefore. The only problem here is the application of Vvalue is going wrong as the scroll pane view is not yet updated with the expanded TitledPane-2.

**Code Sample :**

```
    private void scrollToImage() {
            int imageNum = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()); // Number entered in text field
            int categoryNum = imageNum / 2 + imageNum % 2; // Which category the image number belongs to.
            Bounds scrollViewBounds = mscr.localToScene(mscr.getBoundsInLocal()); // viewport bounds.

            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                System.out.println("Before: " + mvbx.getHeight());
                titledPaneList[categoryNum - 1].setExpanded(true);
                mvbx.applyCss();
                mvbx.layout();
            });

            double scrollHt[] = {0.0};

            //ht of the categories before selected image category.
            for (int idx = 0; idx < (categoryNum - 1); idx++) {
                scrollHt[0] += titledPaneList[idx].getHeight();
            }

            // check if the image is first/second image in the category.
            int imageIdxInCategory = (imageNum % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0;

            // If the selected image is second image in the category,
            // add the titlebar and first image ht to the scroll ht.
            if (imageIdxInCategory > 0) {
                scrollHt[0] += 25 //Title bar ht.
                        + titledPaneList[categoryNum - 1].getInsets().getTop() // titled pane top insets
                        + ((VBox) titledPaneList[categoryNum - 1].getContent()).getChildren().get(0).getBoundsInLocal().getHeight(); // ht of the first image
                // Note: Since, my titledpane contains a vbox which contains the
                //   image number label and imageview,
                //   I am calculating the ht of the first vbox her in the above code.
            }

            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                System.out.println("After: " + mvbx.getHeight());
                double d_ScrollHtPerPix = 1
                        / (mvbx.getHeight()
                        - (scrollViewBounds.getHeight() - mscr.getInsets().getTop() - mscr.getInsets().getBottom()));
                mscr.setVvalue(scrollHt[0] * d_ScrollHtPerPix);
            });
        }
    }
```

**Output :**

When the category of the selected image is collapsed,

Before : 825

After : 825

As u see, the height of the scrollpane content is same even after expanding the collapsed category.

Comment: Why are you calculating the height after expanding titiledpane-2?

Comment: I need to calculate the Vvalue of the scrollpane based on that height to move the scroll to Image-4

Comment: But I think it is possible to calculate the VValue and scroll to image-4 correctly without expanding it.

Comment: I need to expand titledpane-2 since the selected "Image-4" is under it. So, I have to expand titledpane-2 and then move to Image-4. Since Vvalue is something like (<Ht to be scrolled> / <Total ht that can possibly be scrolled>). Total ht that can be scrolled is = <ht of the total scroll pane content> - <ht of the viewport>. If there's is any way to calculate the correct Vvalue in order to scroll to Image-4, Pls let me know.

Comment: Now I understood. So even you expand tittledpane-2, it is not reflected visually, right? By "Titledpane is not yet applied 'physically' on the view" you meant this? Try to wrap scrollTo() method in Platform.runLater().

Comment: exactly. I tried Platform.runLater() but of no use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82444/discussion-between-user3616468-and-uluk-biy).

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could provide a MVCE to observe. Otherwise there will be only guesses.

Comment: okay. Let me come up with MVCE. Thank u for ur support:)