# Width of a VBox is still 0 even though it's larger than 0 in the scene

Tags: java, javafx

I add some child nodes to a VBox, such as button and text. So, the VBox's width should be larger than 0, as it's showing on the scene.

But when I call the width value, it prints out 0.

Examples:

```
vbox.getWidth();      // prints 0
vbox.widthProperty(); // prints 0
```

How do I get the right width of `vbox`?

Comment: Please review both, [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is the vbox already showing in a scene when you call `getWidth()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the height of a node in JavaFX (generate a layout pass)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152642/get-the-height-of-a-node-in-javafx-generate-a-layout-pass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the appearance of your `scene`, the width and height of a `VBox` or any `Node` is not initialized. That's why you are getting 0 as a result. Try to get the size after the `scene` is shown in its `stage`. That way it will show the correct size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
vbox.widthProperty().addListener(e -> System.out.println(vbox.getWidth()));
```