# Change Node.height instantly to Node.prefHeight (AnchorPane)

Tags: java, validation, javafx, properties, refresh

In my fxml I have got a FlowPane in an AnchorPane:

The AnchorPane should change its height as soon as the FlowPane needs another line. I tried to make a changed listener on the Flowpane.heightProperty and it worked. Then I set the prefHeight of the AnchorPane to the new height of the flowPane because I can`t set the height. The problem is that the AnchorPane does not resize instantly. The prefHeight changes as I want it to change, but the height not. It changes after I drag my mouse over the FlowPane.

Code:

```
FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane(flowPane);

titleAnchorPane.setTopAnchor(titleFlowPane, 0.0);
titleAnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(titleFlowPane, 0.0);
titleAnchorPane.setRightAnchor(titleFlowPane, 0.0);

flowPane.heightProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            anchorPane.setPrefHeight(newValue.doubleValue()); 
 });
```

[Bevore I dragged my mouse over it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tziah.png)

[After I dragged my mouse over it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTsLC.png)

I can`t believe that I am the first one asking this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the bottom and top anchors to `0` will result in the `AnchorPane`'s height being resized automatically, unless you've got some other layout constraints in place preventing this:

```
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(flowPane, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(flowPane, 0.0);
```

Note that the actual resizing of `Pane`s is done during the layout pass, which can be triggered manually see jewelsea's answer to this question: [Get the height of a node in JavaFX (generate a layout pass)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152642/get-the-height-of-a-node-in-javafx-generate-a-layout-pass) .