# javafx get height of borderpane

Tags: java, javafx, height, nodes, borderpane

When I want to get the height of a Borderpane in an Anchorpane it always returns 0.0

I tried:
a field : `private double height;`

a method:

```
public void setHeight() {
   height = borderPane.localToScene(borderPane.getBoundsInLocal()).getHeight();
}
```

and a listener in the constructor:

`borderPane.heightProperty().addListener(ob -> setHeight());`

I need it for the method:

```
public double getMiddenY(){
    return y + height/2;
}
```

If I debug, the field `height` changes correctly but at the end it's always 0.0

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Um, can't you just use the `ob` in the listener to directly set `height`, instead of making a separate method? Just a thought

Comment: @1blustone well, that doesn't make a difference ( I tested and it doesn't work)

Comment: I'm almost sure this is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152642/get-the-height-of-a-node-in-javafx-generate-a-layout-pass

Comment: I don't understand "the field `height` changes correctly but at the end it's always 0.0". What do you mean by "at the end" here? Are you saying that `height` changes correctly, but then somehow becomes zero again later?

Comment: @fabian thank you, found a solution. Didn't found that question, so thank you to show me

Comment: @James_D yes, indeed