# Position of Label on GridPane in JavaFX

Tags: netbeans, javafx-8, gridpane

I am using a `GridPane` with several cells. I add `Label` dynamically to each cell. I need each Label's position. My code is like below:

```
@FXML
GridPane graphHolder;

Label label = new Label("A");
label.setWrapText(true);
graphHolder.add(label, 1, 0);
javafx.geometry.Point2D point1 = label.localToScreen(0.0, 0.0);
System.out.println(point1);

Label label2 = new Label("B");
label2.setWrapText(true);
graphHolder.add(label2, 3, 1);
javafx.geometry.Point2D point2 = label2.localToScreen(0.0, 0.0);
System.out.println(point2);
```

This `point1` and `point2` are returning same position `Point2D [x = 834.0000009536743, y = 158.99999225139618]` though they are in different cells. How can I get exact positions of those two Labels? Please help.

Comment: By using the method after the layout has happened...

Comment: Sorry I don't understand

Comment: Nodes are not "put into position" immediately. This happens later during a layout pass, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152642/get-the-height-of-a-node-in-javafx-generate-a-layout-pass