# JavaFX ScrollPane setVvalue() not working properly

Tags: java, javafx, scrollpane

I am testing the JavaFX ScrollPane class and realized that it is not working as I expect, I don't know why. I have the following code:

```
public class Client3 extends Application {

int indexMsg = 0;

Button send;

GridPane root;
ScrollPane msgPane;
GridPane msgPaneContent;
FlowPane writePane;
TextField writeMsg;

Scene scene;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    root = new GridPane();
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    root.setVgap(10);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

    msgPane = new ScrollPane();
    msgPane.setPrefSize(280, 280);
    msgPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);

    msgPaneContent = new GridPane();
    msgPaneContent.setPrefWidth(270);
    msgPaneContent.setVgap(10);

    writePane = new FlowPane(10, 10);
    writePane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    writePane.setPrefWidth(280);

    writeMsg = new TextField();
    writeMsg.setPrefWidth(150);
    writeMsg.setPromptText("Write your message");

    writePane.getChildren().add(writeMsg);

    GridPane.setConstraints(msgPane, 0, 0);
    GridPane.setConstraints(writePane, 0, 1);

    msgPane.setContent(msgPaneContent);
    root.getChildren().addAll(msgPane, writePane);

    writeMsg.setOnAction((ev) -> {

        if (!writeMsg.getText().isEmpty()) {

            TextArea msg = new TextArea(writeMsg.getText());

            msg.setMaxWidth(135);
            msg.setPrefRowCount(msg.getLength() / 21 + 1);
            msg.setWrapText(true);

            GridPane.setConstraints(msg, 0, indexMsg);

            indexMsg++;

            writeMsg.deleteText(0, writeMsg.getText().length());
            msgPaneContent.getChildren().add(msg);

            msgPane.setVvalue(1.0);

        }

    });

    scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Chat App");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch(args);

}

}
```

Basically, I have a `GridPane` as the root with a `ScrollPane` and a `GridPane` as its children. The `ScrollPane` has a children `GridPane`. There is a `TextField` with an `EventHandler` which generates a `TextArea` inside the `GridPane` (the `ScrollPane`'s children). Each `TextArea` object is created in the vertical direction, downwards. I want to set the scrollbar always at its maximum value (`setVvalue(1.0)`) each time a new `TextArea` is added. The thing is that it doesn't seem to work as it should because the vertical value is never set to the maximum after handling the event, but it seems to be set to the maximum value that it had before handling it (the bottom of the previous TextArea added).

Any solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: shot in the dark here, what if you set a prefHeight on the `TextArea msg` objects?  it looks liek the problem is that the height of the ScrolPane has not yet expanded to its new height at the point in which you set it to 1.

Comment: Isn't it ok to `setPrefRowCount` as I did? As I want the `TextArea msg` to be adjusted to the number of text rows, I needed to do it in this way...

Comment: `These values are mapped proportionally onto the layoutBounds of the contained node.`  Print the values of the layoutBounds of the msgPaneContent both before and after placing the `msg` in it.  Also print the value of msg's layoutBounds.  See if doing prefHeight on the `msg` causes any change on what gets printed.

Comment: It seems the layoutBounds don't update after adding `msg`, the update after adding the next TextArea. Before and after first `msg`: 

Before -> BoundingBox [minX:0.0, minY:0.0, minZ:0.0, width:270.0, height:0.0, depth:0.0, maxX:270.0, maxY:0.0, maxZ:0.0] 
After -> BoundingBox [minX:0.0, minY:0.0, minZ:0.0, width:270.0, height:0.0, depth:0.0, maxX:270.0, maxY:0.0, maxZ:0.0].

Moreover, setting prefHeight doesn't solve the problem, unfortunately...

Comment: Should be a pretty similar issue to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152642/get-the-height-of-a-node-in-javafx-generate-a-layout-pass

Comment: Definitely! I needed to call `applyCss()` and `layout()` on the root to update the layoutBounds, now it works! Thank you.