# How to get the actual size of the children during layout computation in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I've just started learning JavaFX for building desktop applications and I currently don't have any personal training yet. Right now regarding the question, I'm trying to make a custom layout that depends its size to the overall size of its children. My problem is about getting the size of each child during height and width computation. Here, I'm using the `getLayoutBounds()` method to retrieve the children's size, but it always return 0 in my case:

```
@Override
protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
  for (int i = 0; i < getChildren().size(); i++) {
    Node node = getChildren().get(i);
    System.out.println(node.getLayoutBounds().getWidth()); // returns 0
  }
}
```

So I guess it is about the ***layout pass*** (say, the child is not laid-out yet). But anyways, if that is the case here or not, how can I get the exact size of the node including the insets, padding, etc.? Thanks for all answers.

---

## UPDATE

I end up using the `prefWidth()` and `prefHeight()` method which is the correct answer. It's my mistake for using the `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` method as I thought the `prefWidth()` method does not include paddings/insets. On the other hand, `getWidth()` actually rely on the *layout pass*, means that, it returns 0 because the nodes (children) are not laid-out yet in the stage, which is what @ᴇʟᴇvᴀтᴇ's answered below is correct.

So for the sake of others whoever come across this, you may want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26152904/8555967) one, and lastly, make sure all CSS stylesheets are properly applied if you are not getting expected result with the `pref`, `min`, `max` methods (see answers by @fabian and @SilasGyeme below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you implement a custom `Region` (or indirect subclass), it's your classes' job to determine the size of the children.

`computePrefWidth` ect. need to consider the size bounds of the children and determine it's own preferred size based on those values. For these kinds of calculation you should use the [`minWidth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#minWidth-double-), [`minHeight`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#minHeight-double-), [`prefWidth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#prefWidth-double-), [`prefHeight`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#prefHeight-double-), [`maxWidth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#maxWidth-double-) and [`maxHeight`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#maxHeight-double-) methods of `Node`.

#### Example

```
@Override
protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
    double size = 0;
    for (Node child : getManagedChildren()) {
        double pW = child.prefWidth(height);
        if (pW > size) {
            size = pW;
        }
    }

    // TODO: consider insets ect...
    return size;
}
```

The above way of determining the pref size would be suitable e.g. for something like a `VBox`.

Answer (score 2):

`getWidth()` returns `0` until you *show* the stage and layout the nodes. After that, they will have a non-zero width.

Use `runLater()` to run actions post layout.

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    // TODO: Calculations based on laid out sizes
});
```

Comment: Saved my hours of searching. Thank you. I'll accept this answer asap.

Comment: Problem with this one, local variable that is meant to be returned cannot be modified inside lambdas. But this is actually useful.

Answer (score 1):

Set the setPrefWidth of the children  ,then access them using getPrefWidth