# How can I use .lookUp() before the stage is shown (or use it once the stage is shown)

Tags: javafx

I want to use .lookup() so that I can create an event for when the content of a TextArea is clicked, but I get null when I use textArea.lookup(".content"). After searching why this is, I found out that it returns null if called before stage.show(). My next reaction was to somehow check for an event that is cast once the stage is shown, but that event is only accessible if you have access to the stage itself, which I do not in this case. What else can I do?

Comment: My suggestion would be to have a handler for `stage.setOnShown()` that calls some methods in one class, that calls a method in another class, that continues down until you get to your class that contains your `TextArea` that will then call the lookup. You may also add a width/height property listener to your `TextArea` because those will change when the stage has been shown, but that approach will cause problems if the text area size changes at all.

Comment: @BlakeOrdway Yeah... I don't think that's going to pass my code review.

Comment: @BlakeOrdway Thanks, the listener for height/width change was exactly the idea I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Don't register the handler at the content node. Let `TextArea` deal with the creation of the content node on its own, register a event handler at the `TextArea` directly and use the `pickResult` of the event to determine, if the click happened inside the node with style class `content`.

```
textArea.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
    Node n = evt.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode();
    while (n != textArea) {
        if (n.getStyleClass().contains("content")) {
            // do something with content node
            System.out.println("content: " + n);
            break;
        }
        n = n.getParent();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate a layout pass on the node:

```
node.applyCss();
node.layout();
```

as defined in the answer to:

- [Get the height of a node in JavaFX (generate a layout pass)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152642/get-the-height-of-a-node-in-javafx-generate-a-layout-pass)

After that, your lookup functions on the node should work as expected.