# ScrollPane.setVvalue() does not update scrollbar in javafx

Tags: javafx, scrollpane

I have a program where I can insert something in a textfield and then after pressing the enter button, it will be displayed as a label in a VBox.
My layout looks like this:
A tab with inside a borderpane with on the bottom a hbox containing a textfield and a button and at the top a scrollpane containing a vbox full of labels.
[image: Screenshot]

This is the code:

```java
        Tab consoleTab = new Tab("Console");
        consoleTab.setClosable(false);
        BorderPane consoleContent = new BorderPane();
        
        TextField commandEntry = new TextField();
        commandEntry.setPromptText("Enter command...");
        Button exe = new Button("Enter");
        HBox input = new HBox(5, commandEntry, exe);
        VBox outputL = new VBox();
        ScrollPane output = new ScrollPane();
        output.setMinHeight(365);
        output.setMaxHeight(365);
        output.setContent(outputL);
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> customEvent = e -> {
            String in = commandEntry.getText();
            if (in.equals("")) return;
            Label inserted = new Label("> "+in);
            inserted.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
            outputL.getChildren().add(inserted);
            commandEntry.setText("");
            Command cmd = new Command(in, outputL);
            cmd.execute(true);
            output.setVvalue(1); // This does not work
        };
        commandEntry.setOnAction(customEvent);
        exe.setOnAction(customEvent);
        consoleContent.setTop(output);
        consoleContent.setBottom(input);
        consoleContent.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        consoleTab.setContent(consoleContent);
```

And this is the `Command.java` class:

```java
public class Command {
    private String command;
    private VBox vbox;
    
    public static final String NEW_FILE = "new_file";
    public static final String OPEN_FILE = "open";
    public static final String SAVE_FILE = "save";
    public static final String LIST_FILES = "list";
    public static final String HELP = "help";
    
    public Command(String command, VBox v){
        this.command = command;
        this.vbox = v;
    }
    
    public void execute(boolean layout){
        String[] args = this.command.split(" ");
        String cmd = args[0];
        String outputText = "";
        switch (cmd){
            case NEW_FILE:
                break;
            case OPEN_FILE:
                outputText = "File opened";
                break;
            case SAVE_FILE:
                break;
            case LIST_FILES:
                outputText = "Files listed";
                break;
            case HELP:
                outputText = "Available commands:\nOPEN: open <file-name>\nLIST: list";
                break;
            default:
                outputText = "Command not found, type help to get the list of available commands";
                break;
        }
        if (layout){
            makeLayout(outputText);
        }
    }
    
    private void makeLayout(String outputText){
        this.vbox.getChildren().add(new Label(outputText));
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I call the `setVvalue(1.0)` method of the scrollpane, this is not setting the scrollbar at the bottom. 
I have tried with using `output.setContent(outputL)` before `output.setVvalue(1.0)` but nothing changes.
**Thanks for any help**

Comment: What do you mean with "layout pass"?

Comment: should I call vbox.layout()?

Comment: @jewelsea unfortunately that solution does not work for me, nothing changes

Comment: It does work, I tried it, you need to add `applyCss()` and `layout()` calls *on the scroll pane* before setting the `Vvalue` of the scroll pane.  Replaced prior comments with an answer, see the answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a layout pass before setting the scroll value.  To generate a layout pass see:

- [Get the height of a node in JavaFX (generate a layout pass)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152642/get-the-height-of-a-node-in-javafx-generate-a-layout-pass)

---

```
// change the content of the scroll pane
// . . .

// generate a layout pass on the scroll pane.
scrollPane.applyCss();
scrollPane.layout();

// scroll to the bottom of the scroll pane.
scrollPane.setVvalue(scrollPane.getVmax());
```

**Why this works**

When the layout pass occurs, the `vValue` of the scroll pane will change to keep the currently visible area displayed rather than the new area.  If you then set the `vValue` to the maximum value, it will change from the value calculated in the layout pass to the maximum value, scrolling the pane to the bottom of the visible content.

**Sample code**

This is just a code snippet to demonstrate the approach, not an executable application.

I did test the approach with the example code in the original question, and it worked fine.

```
public void start(Stage stage) {
    VBox content = new VBox();
    final ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setContent(content);

    Button append = new Button("Append");
    append.setOnAction(e -> appendToScrollPane(scrollPane));
    
    VBox layout = new VBox(scrollPane, append);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
    stage.show();
}

public void appendToScrollPane(ScrollPane scrollPane) {
    // ... actions which add content to the scroll pane ...

    // generate a layout pass on the scroll pane.
    scrollPane.applyCss();
    scrollPane.layout();

    // scroll to the bottom of the scroll pane.
    scrollPane.setVvalue(scrollPane.getVmax());
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks, but the method you wrote `getVMax()` does not exists, you should had wrote `getVmax()` with the small `m`.

Comment: It works also with `1.0` instead of `getVmax()`

Comment: Yes, `1` is the default so by default `1.0` will work.  However, using the method call to `getVmax()` is preferred.  The method call is both nicer to read and more resilient. `1.0` would be wrong if the Vmax were changed from the default value. Using magic constants in code is rarely a good idea.