# Lookup fails the first time a View is shown

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-mobile

Minimal classes to reproduce the issue:

```
import static com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.AppManager.*;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.AppManager;
import com.gpsdemo.view.View1;
import com.gpsdemo.view.View2;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    AppManager appManager = AppManager.initialize();

    public static final String VIEW1 = HOME_VIEW;
    public static final String VIEW2 = "View2";

    @Override
    public void init() {
        appManager.addViewFactory(VIEW1, View1::get);
        appManager.addViewFactory(VIEW2, View2::get);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        appManager.start(stage);
        if (com.gluonhq.attach.util.Platform.isDesktop()) {
            stage.setHeight(600);
            stage.setWidth(360);
            stage.centerOnScreen();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.AppBar;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.MaterialDesignIcon;
import com.gpsdemo.MyApplication;

public class View1 extends View {

    private static View1 INSTANCE;

    public static View1 get() {
        return INSTANCE != null ? INSTANCE : (INSTANCE = new View1());
    }

    private View1() {
        setCenter(new Label("Nothing to see here"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
        appBar.setTitleText("View1");

        var optionsButton = MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(e -> getAppManager().switchView(MyApplication.VIEW2));
        appBar.getActionItems().add(optionsButton);
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Set;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.Node;

import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.AppBar;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.SettingsPane;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.settings.DefaultOption;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.MaterialDesignIcon;

public class View2 extends View {

    private static View2 INSTANCE;

    public static View2 get() {
        return INSTANCE != null ? INSTANCE : (INSTANCE = new View2());
    }

    private View2() {
        var settingsPane = new SettingsPane();
        var option = new DefaultOption<>("Title", "Description", "Category", new SimpleDoubleProperty(), true);
        settingsPane.getOptions().add(option);
        setCenter(settingsPane);

        setOnShown(e -> {
            System.out.println("On shown");
            Set<Node> lookup = settingsPane.lookupAll(".secondary-graphic");
            System.out.println(lookup);
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
        appBar.setTitleText("View2");

        var backButton = MaterialDesignIcon.ARROW_BACK.button(e -> getAppManager().switchToPreviousView().get());
        appBar.setNavIcon(backButton);
    }
}
```

Launch the application normally, `View1` will show.

Click on the button to show `View2`. The first time `View2` is loaded the output is

```
On shown
[]
```

So the `lookup` fails in the `onShown` event.

Click on the back button and then show `View2` again. The output is

```
On shown
[HBox@2c8d8a10[styleClass=secondary-graphic]]
```

which is correct.

If `View2` is set as `HOME_VIEW`, the lookup will find the nodes correctly on the first `onShown` event. This looks like a bug to me. Regardless, I would like the lookup to succeed on the first time so I can configure the view correctly.

Using:

```
<javafx-maven-plugin-version>0.0.8</javafx-maven-plugin-version>
<gluonfx-maven-plugin-version>1.0.14</gluonfx-maven-plugin-version>

<java-version>17</java-version>
<javafx-version>18.0.1</javafx-version>
<charm-version>6.1.0</charm-version>
```

Comment: I've adapted your case to the regular project you get from the Gluon IDE plugin, and it works for me (the first time I open the second view, the lookup already works). But there is a trick: my second view has a show transition, which somehow delays the onShown event. In fact, you can make it work too, simply by calling `settingsPane.applyCss();` before the lookup. Showing/Shown events are still correct, but these don't take into account if the view layout finished applying CSS or not.

Comment: Some background info [Get the height of a node in JavaFX (generate a layout pass)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152642/get-the-height-of-a-node-in-javafx-generate-a-layout-pass).

Comment: @JoséPereda Applying CSS indeed solves the issue, thanks. It was not obvious to me that the `SHOWN` event, which reads "This event happens just after the object is shown.", would not happen after a CSS pass because JavaFX does a CSS pass before it shows (renders) the nodes. For comparison, JavaFX's `DIALOG_SHOWN`, which reads "This event occurs on dialog just after it is shown.", does happen after CSS is applied. I would still argue that the `SHOWN` event is misleading and behaves more like `DIALOG_SHOWING`.

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks, I'm aware of the CSS pass mechanism. I explained above what I was not aware of.

Comment: Well, `LifecycleEvent.SHOWN` is a custom event that is triggered when you replace one `View` node with another and the transition to do so ends. Without transition, it just mainly: `getChildren().add(newView); getChildren().remove(oldView); fireEvent(SHOWN);`. Maybe a request layout should be needed before firing the event...

Comment: @JoséPereda That could work if there are no side-effects as a result of this change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue is that the `SHOWN` event does not happen after a css pass is applied, therefore the lookup fails. A fix can be to manually do a css pass before the lookup, inside the `SHOWN` handler:

```
setOnShown(e -> {
    System.out.println("On shown");
    settingsPane.applyCss();
    Set<Node> lookup = settingsPane.lookupAll(".secondary-graphic");
    System.out.println(lookup);
});
```

This is confusing because the `SHOWN` event does not actually happen after the view is fully shown (in which case a css pass has happened). The event also behaves differently than JavaFX's dialog `DIALOG_SHOWN` event, that does happen after the dialog is fully shown (including a css pass).