# JavaFX TextField.setPrefColumnCount() not working

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I am seeing some odd behavior, where the preferred width of a `javafx.scene.control.TextField` isn't being computed correctly after calling `setPrefColumnCount`.  My specific use case is for a `javafx.scene.control.Spinner` control.  My code is as follows:

```
@FXML
private Spinner<Integer> mySpinner;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    mySpinner.getEditor().setPrefColumnCount(3);
}
```

After executing the above, I get a spinner that is barely large enough for a single character (the spinner value is pictured at 999):

[image: Incorrectly Sized Spinner]

Does anyone know the correct way to set the width of a `TextField` based on the number of digits I want to be able to display?  I am using JRE 8u77 on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 x64, in case it matters.

**EDIT**

I have realized that part of the problem is that even if I measure the text via the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13020490/960115), I still don't know what to set `Spinner.prefWidth` to.  In addition, it appears that setting the `prefWidth` on the underlying `TextField` editor is no different than setting it on the `Spinner` object.  Is there some way to get the `TextField.padding` property (returns 0 within the `initialize` method, even though it is eventually set to 7 on each side)?  How about a way to query the width of the up/down arrows?  If I could somehow compute/query these values, then I could use the measure text technique.  Without that information, however, I can't figure out how to go about it.

Comment: That property has never worked for me, either. I got around it by using a different method to determine relative display scaling. I created a variable that is sort of like an em value in css. `final static double em = Math.rint(new Text("").getLayoutBounds().getHeight());` and then I use it as my basis for relative width and height by using a multiplier. `navButtons.setButtonMinWidth(5*em);`

Comment: I tried to do something like that based on [measuring text](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13020490/960115) containing the desired number of zero characters.  However, in the specific case of the `Spinner` object, I am struggling with how to apply that measurement.  It appears that setting the `prefWidth` of the underlying `TextField` must also account for the `padding` property (returns 0 within the `initialize` method, even though it will end up being 7) and the up/down buttons (whose width I can't seem to get).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding property returns `0` because the `TextField` not being layed out at that time doesn't have any CSS style applied to it. Try to get the padding after the `TextField` is added to the `SceneGraph.`

At that time you're also able to use the `Nodes` `lookup` method to get the `StackPane` which contains the arrow button:

```
 StackPane upArrow = (StackPane) spnr.lookup(".increment-arrow-button");
 StackPane downArrow = (StackPane) spnr.lookup(".decrement-arrow-button");
```

Then it should be possible to calculate the width for the spinner:

```
 double spinnerWidth = calculateWidth("123", spnr.getEditor()) + upArrow.getWidth();

 private double calculateWidth(String value, TextField textField) {
        Text text = new Text(value);
        text.setFont(textField.getFont());
        Insets insets = textField.getInsets();
        return insets.getLeft() + text.prefWidth(-1) + insets.getRight();
    }
```

Comment: Is there some event I can subscribe to that is fired "after the `TextField` is added to the `SceneGraph`"?  If not, what is the standard practice to achieve this functionality?

Comment: You can use any of the mentioned methods after the node in question is attached to a `Scene` in a `Stage`that is showing. So after showing a `Stage` by `stage.show()` you can call the method you need.

Comment: All of my JavaFX controllers were already implementing an interface that includes a `setStage` method (so I could set the owner for pop-up dialogs).  For those components that include a `Spinner` control, I registered for the `Stage.onShown` event, and perform this width calculation within that handler.

Comment: One final note: I had to add `prefWidth="0"` to the FXML on the `Spinner` element for this to work.  Otherwise, the layout was not performed when setting the `prefWidth` property value after the `Stage` was shown.