# Why are some text bounds inconsistent in JavaFX and how can I avoid it?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using a [`Text`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/Text.html) node to compute the dimensions of a string, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015698), summarized as:

```java
new Text("some text").getLayoutBounds();
```

The dimensions returned are not always the same at different execution points, *for the same input string*, and everything else being the same (font, etc.). It seems that the inconsistencies are somehow related to the interaction of the backspace with a `TextArea`, *even if this TextArea is not related to the Text node.*

It's an intermittent/non-deterministic problem, but others were able to reproduce it with the following code:

```java
public class Test extends Application {
    private Text text = new Text();
    
    public static void main(String... args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            text.setText(newValue);
            System.out.println(String.format("height=%.1f", text.getLayoutBounds().getHeight()));
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(textArea)));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Typing a few "X" characters, I get (on Windows): `height=16.0`. After typing backspace (but when there are still a few "X" characters in the string), I get `height=17.0`. If I type some more characters, the height stays `17.0`, then arbitrarily shifts back to 16.0, then 17.0, etc. Other users report different kinds of erratic behavior.

- If you replace the `TextArea` with `TextField`, the problem goes away (!)
- It doesn't matter where the `Text` node is initialized.
- While debugging, I see that that the `valid` flag is `false` in all cases in `LazyBoundsProperty#get`, so bounds seem to be recomputed for each new character.
- I get the same behavior on JavaFX 11.0.2 as JavaFX 16.

What causes this inconsistency, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: I'm guessing it creates space for the padding between different lines of text at some point (even if it's not strictly needed). I guess the question is why you care about the size of the text displayed by the text area; maybe there is a different way entirely to get at whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Thing to note: the problem is not necessarily related to the <backspace>. When programmatically changing the text to a new String with shorter length (as well for the `Text` as the `TextArea`) the height does also change to 17.0. See also [this gist](https://gist.github.com/aron-hoogeveen/0425fc80fa80cc797bbb310c203d8683)

Comment: Above mentioned Gist makes me suspect that the JavaFX engine reuses some graphical text components for rendering the same (or equal) Strings. Indeed, only when setting the text value of a `TextArea` to that of the `Text` element does the height change occur. (Note however that I have no knowledge whatsoever about the inner workings of JavaFX)